# Calculating the twist angle around a vector from a rotation matrix

Tags: python, math, geometry

I need to calculate the twist angle of a rope attached to a swinging object. I have the vector direction of the rope, the rotation matrix of the object and the x y and z of the objects reference frame, but I am a bit lost on how to move forward.

The rope can be assumed to be taut, and the object is fastened securely to the rope. The object has no constrained angular degrees of freedom. The system swings in such a way that the rope is not aligned to any axis or plane.

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1kZW.jpg)

As in the diagram above, the object does have a pitch that can occur, as well as roll and yaw. I need to track how much the rope gets twisted (theta) as the object moves. It's like a yo-yo that you have to let hang and spin to remove the twist that has built up in the string after playing with it. I need to track how much of that twist has built up in the yo-yo string during play (over time). If I can calculate the angle, I can track how much it rotates each time step.

I have tried projecting a vector of an axis of the object onto the orthogonal plane of the rope vector, and calculating it's angle to a (0, 0, 1) projection; I've tried tracking yaw, roll, etc. but each of these seems to break down under certain circumstances. Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you add a simple figure that visualizes your problem? I have a hard time understanding your goal.

Comment: Sorry about that - I drew out a figure and added it in, and tried making it clearer with the yo-yo analogy; hopefully that communicates it better